Inductive charging with different W -- Safe for battery?
Is it safe to use a 1.2 W inductive charger for my electric toothbrush (Braun) that originally comes with a 0.9 W charger?
Both chargers otherwise say 220 - 240 V ~ and 50 - 60 Hz.
Is this safe for the battery or are there any other things to consider?

First let's clarify that what most people call "chargers" are NOT chargers at all. They are power supplies.
The charger proper is inside the device (toothbrush, wireless mouse, Bluetooth headphones, smartphone, etc.).
So, the question isn't "is the charger safe for the battery?": it is  safe since it is inside the device, next to the battery, and you can't really change it. If it were unsafe, Braun would have a product recall to deal with :)
The question is, then: "is the power supply safe for use with the device?"
TL;DR: Likely it is.

As long as the wireless supply is made by Braun and physically fits the toothbrush, it should be OK. Those supplies all work the same way and are interchangeable.

Both chargers otherwise say 220-240V~ and 50-60Hz.

What matters is the output of the supply, not the input. And the only way to check that is to add a coil of wire around the supply's protrusion, add a load, measure the voltage and current, and compare the two supplies side by side.
But Braun thankfully aren't too evil yet and they don't make incompatible supplies that are physically interchangeable.
The power rating on the supply is how much power the charger consumes from mains, it has nothing to do with what sort of waveform it outputs. So you can't say much, other than "hey, it looks like the the supplies have same shape and similar specs and fit my toothbrush, it should be OK". And OK it is.
I have used my Braun (branded Oral-B) toothbrushes with supplies from all over the world - some rated for 100-120V~ only, some for 220-240V~, some home-made. It is, thankfully, a basic wireless power transfer scheme that is not over-designed. A lot of consumer electronics try to lock charging down, unfortunately, to try and make money on chargers..., with the ensuing e-waste craziness :(

thanks, I learned a lot!
